# Unable to simulate Smart-car-use-case - mimik

Tags: edgeengine

I have been trying to solve the **Smart-car-use-case**. I took Car 1 as **RaspberryPi** and Car 2 as **Laptop**(Windows). I have an image of obstacle in **Pi** which is used as the dummy data.

As per the assumption any image on the local machine (here **Pi board**) can be taken as the dummy data.

And as in the step "***[C2]  → mSuperdrive mimik add a media Obj locally (Car 1)***",  I have to use the image file path (ex:**home/pi/Desktop/image.jpg**) as the url, so the postman should be running in Pi board.

But postman is not supported with RaspberryPi

[image]

then **how can I simulate this problem.**

Answer (score 0):

On the laptop (Car2) if you have postman go to the [C2] → mSuperdrive mimik add a media Obj locally (Car 1) call and open it in a postman tab. On the right-hand side there is a "Code snippet" tab. Open this tab and set the code you want to see to "cURL" this will convert the [C2] → mSuperdrive mimik add a media Obj locally (Car 1) API call into a cURL command. Copy all the code in code snippet and move it to the PI. On the PI you will need to install cURL. Once cURL is installed paste the code snippet into terminal to simulate the call. Please make sure you use the right tokens and set the right paths before pasting the command into terminal.

Comment: In the above method we are still using the image in Laptop (Car 2). The problem is, Car 1 ( Pi )  have an image of the obstacle and Car 2 ( Laptop ) can view the image generated by the first car. We need to use an image in Pi right?